# How to convert Xml using xslt transform when simple type is repetating

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt

I am trying to transform one xml to another xml using xslt transform.
when there is a complex node repeating then all nodes are properly transformed and things are fine.
If the simple type is repeating then same count of nodes are transformed but value of all nodes are value of the very first node.

This is a part of xml

```
<GetDataResult xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">0</string>
    <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">1</string>
    <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">2</string>
    <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">3</string>
</GetDataResult>
```

this is my Xslt snippet part

```
<response>
    <xsl:for-each select="ns1:GetDataResponse/ns1:GetDataResult/ns2:string" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <item>
            <xsl:value-of select="/ns1:GetDataResponse/ns1:GetDataResult/ns2:string/text()" />
        </item>
    </xsl:for-each>
</response>
```

i tried few combinations of Xslt for each loop, however the final result is as below. all the items have value of the first repeating node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Fields>
    <response>
        <item>0</item>
        <item>0</item>
        <item>0</item>
        <item>0</item>
    </response>
</Fields>
```

this it transformation code snippet.

```
    XmlDocument xslDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xslDoc.InnerXml = XsltCode;
    System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform xslTransform = new System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform();
    StringWriter xmlResult = new StringWriter();
    try
    {
        //Load XSL Transform Object
        xslTransform.Load(xslDoc, new XmlUrlResolver(), null);
        //Load the xsl parameter if Any
        System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList xslArgs = new System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList();
        //Call the actual Transform method
        xslTransform.Transform(xmlDoc, null, xmlResult, new XmlUrlResolver());
    }
    catch
    { }
    string firstParse = xmlResult.ToString();
```

Comment: The problem is most likely this select="/ns1:GetDataResponse/ns1:GetDataResult/ns2:string/text()".  change it to <xsl:value-of select="."/> and see what happens.

Comment: if i use <xsl:value-of select="."/> then  transformed is <item>0123</item>

Comment: there was one mistake... @TTY  <xsl:value-of select="."/> works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use relative XPath to get the value of current `ns2:string` in every iteration instead :

```
<xsl:for-each select="ns1:GetDataResponse/ns1:GetDataResult/ns2:string" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <item>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </item>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: resulting transformed is <item>0123</item>.. instead of 4 <item> nodes.